# How to mock (change value) of global variables in javascript using jest/sinon etc?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, sinon

I'm writing test cases for a ts file which contains a global variable like so:

```
let cachedSecret: any;

const find = () => {
   if(cachedSecret){
     //return something
   } else {
       //return something else
   }
}
```

I need to find a way so that for one of the test cases I can mock cachedSecret's value as some string and in the other test case it's value should be null.

I'm using jest and sinon but I haven't been able to find a way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: I guess you should mock that class in the first place.

Comment: The code lacks the context Is there a real reason to consider it a global? When evaluated in a module, `let cachedSecret` declares *local* variable and not global. And no, there's no way to access it with Jest. Put everything you need to be mocked to modules that could be mocked with jest.mock.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [rewire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire) package to mock the variable defined in module scope.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
let cachedSecret: any;

const find = () => {
  console.log('cachedSecret:', cachedSecret, typeof cachedSecret);
  if (cachedSecret) {
    return 'something';
  } else {
    return 'something else';
  }
};

export { find };
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import rewire from 'rewire';

describe('63955435', () => {
  it('should return something', () => {
    const mod = rewire('./');
    const revert = mod.__set__('cachedSecret', true);
    const actual = mod.find();
    expect(actual).toEqual('something');
    revert();
  });

  it('should return something else', () => {
    const mod = require('./');
    const actual = mod.find();
    expect(actual).toEqual('something else');
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/63955435/index.test.ts
  63955435
    ✓ should return something (202ms)
    ✓ should return something else (40ms)

cachedSecret: true boolean
  console.log src/stackoverflow/63955435/index.ts:4
    cachedSecret: undefined undefined

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.4s, estimated 11s
```

`npm script`:

```json
"test:rewire": "ts-node -O '{\"module\":\"commonjs\"}' node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/63955435